# How can I debug the "Process exited with non-zero code: 4294963248" bug?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I need help regarding fixing the following error:-

I'm getting the above mentioned error (see question title) after installing dependencies of **expo react native**.

Below is a log of the error in question from my command line:-

> Process exited with non-zero code: 4294963248
>
> > [07:55:23] Installing dependencies... npm WARN tarball tarball data for lottie-react-native@2.5.0 (sha1-BxG4s0vsd0FVLCS3Hv09TKs0dXE=)
> >     seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time. npm WARN
> >     expo-google-sign-in@2.0.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.55.4 but
> >     none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
> >     WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11 requires a peer of
> >     react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer
> >     dependencies yourself. npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.0-alpha.11
> >     requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You
> >     must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN url-loader@1.1.2
> >     requires a peer of webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You
> >     must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! path
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin']
>   npm ERR!   cause: npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
>   unlink
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin'
>   npm ERR!      errno: -4048, npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!
>   syscall: 'unlink', npm ERR!      path: npm ERR!
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules\.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin'
>   }, npm ERR!   stack: npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not
>   permitted, unlink
>   \'C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules\.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'unlink', npm ERR!   path: npm ERR!
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\HilfyerMobApp\node_modules\.staging\lottie-react-native-b0472480\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin'
>   } npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating
>   system. npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a
>   text editor or antivirus), npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to
>   access it. npm ERR! npm ERR! If you believe this might be a
>   permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the
>   file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the
>   command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-14T00_04_55_245Z-debug.log
>   [08:04:55] Process exited with non-zero code: 4294963248 [08:04:55]
>   Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a broken tarball in your cache. Try running this and then re-installing.

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

This will clean out the cache so you can re-fetch all of the necessary NPM files.

Comment: hi Oscar, i'm using windows O.S

Comment: The first line of code should be enough to clean out the cache for you to re-install. Just ran that one in the directory of you project then do `npm install`